# Radio Button mutlilevel filter using jquery html

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, radio-group

I am working with multilevel filter based on radio selection, where I need to open hierarchy on parent selection

As on simple hide and show jQuery function I tried hiding fields with hardcode coding,

And I need smart way to handle lengthy hierarchy filter, which I am not able to do with code I have done

Here is a JSfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/Lqomhwg5/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function openProtocolView(){
                $('input:radio[name=ProtocolViewVerticalSingleBoth]').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', false); });
                $('input:radio[name=ACodebcode]').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', false); });
                $('input:radio[name=bcode_ccvs]').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', false); });
                $("#ProtocolViewChild").css("display","block")
                hideAllOtherViewThanProtocol()
            }
            function openSmartView(){
                $("#smartViewChild").css("display","block")
                hideAllOtherViewThanSmart()
            }
            function openShapeView(){
                $("#shapeViewChild").css("display","block")
                $("#shapeViewChildVerticalSingleSide").css("display","none")
                $('input:radio[name=shapeViewVerticalSingleBoth]').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', false); });
                hideAllOtherViewThanShape()
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-div">
            <div class="View-name" onclick="openProtocolView()">
                <label for="ProtocolView">Protocol View</label>
                <input type="radio" id="ProtocolView" name="MainView" value="ProtocolView">
            </div>
            <div class="View-name" onclick="openSmartView()">
                <label for="smartView">Smart View</label>
                <input type="radio" id="smartView" name="MainView" value="smartView">
            </div>
            <div class="View-name" onclick="openShapeView()">
                <label for="shapeView">Shape View</label>
                <input type="radio" id="shapeView" name="MainView" value="shapeView">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So is there any library or trick to handle the same with so many child and grand child filter options? Thanks.

Comment: why you don't use tree view?
https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Dynamic-Tree-View-Plugin-With-Checkbox-Support-jQuery-Treejs.html
or 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/26909658/11143288

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, I just want to find the same. I'll update it as per my requirement.